# Detecting surrounding electronics or electrical devices

Tags: sensor, detection, emc

I'm working on a project which requires using EM antennas or sensors array to identify and locate surrounding electrical devices such as cellphone, laptop, ipod, remote...

I'm not a EMF guy. I don't know which frequency band I should be using. Is there any commercial sensors available?

Comment: Do you expect the surrounding devices to run a program to identify themselves and broadcast their identity via Bluetooth or 802.11 wifi, or are you trying to detect them without modification?  The former seems doable, the later will be extremely difficult to generalize.  Are you sure you meant to group 'remote' in there, and are you looking for an iPod touch (which has bluetooth/wifi)?

Comment: @reemrevnivek It almost sounds like he is making a spectrum analyzer that could be used for regulatory validation, but I could be reading it wrong.

Comment: you'd need either an array of antennas, probably well spaced out or a directional antenna on a motorized gimble to get direction.  Distance...you can kind of get with an array of antennas, but without knowing whats in the beam path it won't be very accurate.  Basically what you get on your cell phone when you let it figure out your position based on cell tower information.  Accuracy could obviously vary based on the positions of the antennas in relation to the source your trying to detect.

Answer (score 1):

One cheap idea is to use an [IM-me as a sub-1Ghz spectrum analyser](http://ossmann.blogspot.com/2010/03/16-pocket-spectrum-analyzer.html).

The [Wi-Spy](http://www.metageek.net/) is a cheap 2.4GHz spectrum analyser, which can help characterise WiFi and ZigBee.

A fun site to look at is http://1010.co.uk/org/scrying.html

They have a range of projects designed to pick up signals.